# Regex - Group everything until last occurence

Tags: python, regex

When working on this string:

```
see.Ya23.v2.0023.jpg
```

I already found out I could get the last occurence of a number by using:

```
(?P<Frame>\d+(?!.*\d))
```

It gives me the group containing "0023".
But how do I group everything until that happens?

If I do this:

```
(?P<Sequence>.*)(?P<Frame>\d+(?!.*\d))
```

My two groups contain "see.Ya23.v2.002" and "3", when I would like to have to have them contain "see.Ya23.v2." and "0023".

Hope you can help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it completely.

just in the first group you can add the lazy indicator `?` after any match. that causes to drop the selection at the first possible possition.

```
(?P<Sequence>.*?)(?P<Frame>\d+(?!.*\d))
```

this will give you
`see.Ya23.v2.` and `0023`

and if you also want to avoid selecting the dot

```
(?P<Sequence>.*?)\.(?P<Frame>\d+(?!.*\d))
```

the result is `see.Ya23.v2` and `0023`

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and quickest way is to put a negative assertion for a digit
before your digit expression at the start of the `Frame` group.
This will make sure the Frame is the last complete set of digits and
still allow a greedy Sequence match which give a performance boost.

```
(?P<Sequence>.*)(?P<Frame>(?<!\d)\d+(?!.*\d))
```

https://regex101.com/r/LCUoCR/1

Answer (score 0):

The problem is explained in [my Youtube video](https://youtu.be/XDWK_tK2LUE?t=179) related to how *backtracking* works in regex.

In short: the `.*` part matches the whole string first, and then the regex engine starts stepping back through the string to accommodate a part for the subsequent patterns, i.e. for `\d+(?!.*\d)`. Once the `3` is found in `see.Ya23.v2.0023.jpg`, this pattern matches, and the regex engine returns a match.

All you need is to make sure the char before the `\d+` is a non-digit char and you need to use

```py
(?P<Sequence>(?:.*\D)?)(?P<Frame>\d+)(?!.*\d)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LBR7p4/1).